# error: 'RCC_ABH1Periph_GPIOD' undeclared (first use in this function) Build Error

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I get the error: error: 'RCC_ABH1Periph_GPIOD' undeclared (first use in this function) when building, anyone know why?

This is for the STM32F4 Discovery board.

The line throwing the error is:

RCC_AHB1PeriphClockLPModeCmd(RCC_ABH1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);

I have included all files that are needed.

```
#include "defines.h"
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_adc.h"



//Configure sysTick
static __IO uint32_t timingDelay;

void Delay(uint32_t nTime)
{
    timingDelay = nTime;
    while (timingDelay != 0);
}

void sysTick_Handler(void)
{
    if (timingDelay != 0x00)
    {
        timingDelay--;
    }
}

//Configure GPIO
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_initStruct;

void init_led(void)
{
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockLPModeCmd(RCC_ABH1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
    GPIO_initStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_12 | GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14 | GPIO_Pin_15;
    GPIO_initStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUT;
    GPIO_initStruct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_initStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    GPIO_initStruct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_initStruct(GPIOD, &~GPIO_initStruct);
}

int main(void)
{
    if (SysTick_Config((SystemCoreClock/1000)));
    while (1);

    init_led();

    while(1)
    {
        GPIO_ToggleBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_12 | GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14 |   GPIO_Pin_15);
        Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could write a minimal example, considering the error, all your code is certainly not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This RCC_**ABH1**Periph_GPIOD should be RCC_**AHB1**Periph_GPIOD.
Check your code more attentively before write question!

Comment: Thanks, sometimes you just need someone who hasnt wrote it to look at it and they find obvious mistakes within seconds that the author cant see easily